# how to use elif with pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, if-statement

I have a sales dataframe which looks like below

```
    Company         Sales
    MC                360.0
    MC                340.0
    MC                338.5
    MC                335.5
    MC                235.0
    MC                235.0
    MC                234.0
    MC                127.0
    MC                121.0
    MC                120.5
```

I want to create a new column based on the values of Sales column
And my output table should be like

```
    CompanyCode     ActivityDate    Category
    MC                360.0         Fast Mover
    MC                340.0         Fast Mover
    MC                338.5         Fast Mover
    MC                335.5         Fast Mover
    MC                235.0         Medium Fast Mover
    MC                235.0         Medium Fast Mover
    MC                234.0         Medium Fast Mover
    MC                127.0         Slow Mover
    MC                121.0         Slow Mover
    MC                120.5         Slow Mover
```

I tried elif statement

```
if df['Sales']>=300:
   df['Category'] = 'Fast Movers'
elif (df['Sales']>=200) & (df['Sales'] < 300) :
   df['Category'] = 'Medium Fast Movers'
else:
   df['Category'] = 'Slow Movers'
```

Not sure if my approach is correct. I will appreciate your kind help and effort.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`np.select()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html)

```
df["Category"] = np.select([df.Sales>=300, df.Sales<200], 
                           ["Fast Movers", "Slow Movers"], 
                           default="Medium Fast Movers")
```

Answer (score 3):

use a lambda function (or a named function) with `apply`

```
df.Category = df.Sales.apply(
    lambda x: 'Fast Movers' if x >=300 else ('Medium Fast Movers' if x >= 200 else 'Slow Movers')
)
```

instead of the lambda, a named function can be defined like this:

```
def move_speed(x):
    if x >= 300:
        return 'Fast Movers'
    if x >= 200:
        return 'Medium Fast Movers'
    return 'Slow Movers'
```

or, you can assign each condition individually using `loc`

```
df.loc[df.Sales > 300, 'Category'] = 'Fast Movers'
df.loc[df.Sales < 200, 'Category'] = 'Slow Movers'
df.Category.fillna('Medium Fast Movers', inplace=True)
```

both would produce this data frame:

```
  Company  Sales            Category
0      MC  360.0         Fast Movers
1      MC  340.0         Fast Movers
2      MC  338.5         Fast Movers
3      MC  335.5         Fast Movers
4      MC  235.0  Medium Fast Movers
5      MC  235.0  Medium Fast Movers
6      MC  234.0  Medium Fast Movers
7      MC  127.0         Slow Movers
8      MC  121.0         Slow Movers
9      MC  120.5         Slow Movers
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using a second dataframe and **`pd.IntervalIndex`**.  This can make your code cleaner if you have a large number of ranges.

***Setup***

```
ranges = pd.DataFrame({
    'START': [0, 200, 300],
    'STOP': [200, 300, float('inf')],
    'CLASS': ['Slow Workers', 'Medium Workers', 'Fast Workers']
})

#                          CLASS  START        STOP
# [0.0, 200.0)      Slow Workers      0  200.000000
# [200.0, 300.0)  Medium Workers    200  300.000000
# [300.0, inf)      Fast Workers    300         inf

ranges.index = pd.IntervalIndex.from_arrays(ranges.START, ranges.STOP, closed='left')
```

**`map`**

```
df['Category'] = df.Sales.map(ranges.CLASS)

# Result

  Company  Sales        Category
0      MC  360.0    Fast Workers
1      MC  340.0    Fast Workers
2      MC  338.5    Fast Workers
3      MC  335.5    Fast Workers
4      MC  235.0  Medium Workers
5      MC  235.0  Medium Workers
6      MC  234.0  Medium Workers
7      MC  127.0    Slow Workers
8      MC  121.0    Slow Workers
9      MC  120.5    Slow Workers
```